# Way to change ip after launch in amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

My ec2 instances are up  only for 1-2 hours in a day. I don't want to pay to elastic ips.

Without rebooting the instance is there any way change the IP address to any other 
 ephemeral IP?

If I stop the instance and then boot it, then a new IP is assigned. But I don't want to stop and then restart it.

Comment: Reading your question again: It's not realy about preserving the IP, it's more about switching IPs, right? What exactly is your use-case?

Comment: The only use-case I've seen for people wanting to change IP addresses is to scrape websites, where those websites block too much usage from a particular IP address. If this is the case, please note that we do not encourage people to violate the rules of websites by hiding their scraping activities.

Comment: That's also what came to my mind. I wonder if there's a legit use-case for switching the IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the internal IP of your instance, which is also preserved on reboot.

A public IP is automatically assigned and you cannot change it. The only way to set a public IP is using elastic IPs.

If you don't necessarily need to rely on the IP, you can only use a domain name (for example using Route53) and assign it to your instance when you start it.
Using a domain name is a preferred method in the internet for quite some time, except you have some rare use-case where you really need to have a fixed IP (like when hosting a DNS server).

Comment: Do you mean that I must stop and start the instance after a few seconds? To have it automatically assigned new ephemeral IP?

Comment: That's correct, but I think you already figured that out, because you wrote: "If I stop the instance and then boot it, then a new IP is assigned."